# why does matplotlib add colours to my grey scale image?

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to display an image in matplotlib. The image only has grey scale. When the image displays in matplotlib it has spurious colours added to it.

I converted the original image to png from jpeg. It did not help.

The code I used is;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img = mpimg.imread('blok-1-mode.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

I swap the image with a colour image and it reads and displays it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the [documentation from imshow](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html?highlight=imshow#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) and [Image tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/images.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-images-py).

The gist of it, is that if your data does not contain RGB information (i.e. your data is NxM, and not NxMx3), then the image is displayed with a colormap (`viridis` by default). If you want to plot the image in greyscale, then try

```
plt.imshow(img, cmap='Greys')
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, your solution did indeed work.  The cmap argument in imshow did however assign greyscale pixel values to each pixel in the image that do not appear identical to the original pixel values. I have to confirm that for every pixel value though. When PIL is used this does not happen, I will refer to the documentation as referenced. Thank you for your time.